# Angular 2 , loadChildren content in a variable

Tags: json, angular, typescript, router

I try to configure the Angular 2 router from a Json File,
i try lot of things but it still have something wrong.

The last fail test :

```
let mEx = "../dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule";

let mdEx = mEx.split('#');
let mymod =() => require(mdEx[0])[mdEx[1]];

{ path: 'dashboard', loadChildren:mymod}
```

If i try to load from a var i have this issue :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module "."
```

EDIT : 
Another test that doesn't Work

```
let mymod = "app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule"; 
{ path: 'dashboard', loadChildren:mymod}
```

In that case the router doesn't find the module..

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module'.
```

But that's work if i do `loadChildren:'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule‌​'`

but not with the module path in a variable, i began to be crazy... ;) –

EDIT 2 :

It seem that the problem come with webpack ng-router-loader
I search how to resolve this, because my project use this librarie...

Do you have an idea of what i can do for this ? 
Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0):

Load children will works with the whole url.

```
{ path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: "../dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule"}
```

You don't need to load the dashboard with `require()`. The router still do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, But i have the same problem, if i do let mymod = "app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule";

{ path: 'dashboard', loadChildren:mymod}  In that case  the router doesn't find the module.. That's work if i do loadChildren:'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' but not with the module path in a variable, i begin to be crazy... ;)